# How to handle invalid action on a state in functional programming

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, game-development

I'm currently working on a functional programming style implementation of the game Tetris. Each tick or user input is handled using functions where I pass in the state of the game (grid with pointer to where the current active block is), and that function returns a new state.

If the user presses left, but the current active block is already to the utmost left side, what should I do? I would like to let the outer code block know that it wasn't able to create a new state, but what pattern seems best? I've got a couple of styles, am leaning towards just throw and catch the error as I feel it reads and expresses the intent best.

```
onLeft() {
  // try catch style
  try {
    this.state = moveLeft(this.state);
  } catch (err) {
    // oh no!
  }

  // callback style
  moveLeft(
    (err) => {
     // oh no!
    }, 
    (newState) => {
      this.state = newState 
    }
  );

  // return false for invalid state
  this.state = moveLeft(this.state) || this.state;
}
```

Comment: Do you see any action you would need to perform in such a case? In the actual use case, I don't see any. The `moveLeft` action will in that border case just return the same state, and nothing else needs to happen. It is not an exception: users are allowed to press left when the block is already at its left most position. It is just part of the behaviour that the block does not move any further.

Comment: @trincot that's right, but I might want to trigger an animation. There are other actions which matter though: such as when I place a new block to the grid, but it is not possible due to no place on the grid, which means game-over. So the error scenario would be catched with the game-over flow.

Comment: I would personally reserve raising errors for unexpected errors, not for what falls within the game rules. But opinions may differ on this.

Comment: Exactly, although I feel that the try/catch feels in place, I know that usually it is really used for error-flows that are not supposed to happen. But I don't like the alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

I know games have a lot of state and that most game dev resources lean heavily on oop but state is getting mutated in multiple places here. This mitigates the advantages of fp and leads to confusing situations like this.

If you are interested in a fp pattern, consider describing the change in state as data and passing it off to some effect that actually does the mutation.

When multiple lines of code are mutating state, and youre using methods in a class to do the actual mutations you're really doing oop. Handling illegal player moves as errors does not make sense to me. Why would you design a program that allows users to throw errors? If you just catch them and do something else then why not create your own container for handling them?